# UITableView to UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have created a simple app that reads data from my JSON URL and as I moved on I realized when I really need to use is UICollectionView because my cells are complicated.

I've been checking on the net how I can read json to the UICollectionView and found some sample code I can use and adjust to fit mine.

My problem is that I'm a total iOS beginner, and I have no idea why I get the following error:

```
No visible @interface for 'KivaViewController' declares the selector 'myCollectionView'
```

in the following line:

```
[[self myCollectionView]setDataSource:self];
```

Hope someone can explain this issue to me,
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

KIvaViewController has the UITableView view named "table" instead of the UICollectionView view.

```
self.table.dataSource = self;
```

https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModelDemo_iOS/KivaViewController.m

Answer (score 0):

The `No visible @interface for 'KivaViewController' declares the selector 'myCollectionView'` error means there's no method like that in KivaViewController. You'd best create the CollectionViewController yourself, since the KivaViewController is also only used for TableViews and not CollectionViews.

Comment: What method "like that"?

Comment: myCollectionView is what I refer to, but I take it that it's a property. (Please use dot notation for properties.) There's no myCollectionView property in the KivaViewController.